# BibTeX using inconsistent name format in the case of two authors

Tags: biblatex

I recently started using `biblatex` (my installation is TeX Live 2010). My preamble syntax is:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

When I cite a source with two authors, the bibliography entry prints the author names using an inconsistent format. For instance, suppose my `.bib` file entry is:

```
@book{Abramowitz,
author = "Abramowitz, M. and Stegun, I.",
title  = "Handbook of Mathematical Functions",
publisher = {Dover Publications},
year = "1965" }
```

If I issue the command `\parencite{Abramowitz}` in my document, the bibliography entry prints as:

> Abramowitz, M. and I. Stegun (1965). Handbook of Mathematical Functions. Dover Publications.

Notice that the name format used for the first author is inconsistent with that used for the second author. The first author is printed using Last Name First format, but the second author is printed using Last Name Last format. What I'd like is for the entry to print like this:

> Abramowitz, M. and Stegun, I. (1965). Handbook of Mathematical Functions. Dover Publications.

How do I get `biblatex` to do what I want? Is this inconsistency a known `biblatex` bug?

Comment: It surely is no bug. The inversion in the first author helps in finding the entry alphabetically; in the following authors it serves no purpose and it's customary only in Hungarian (among the western languages) to write "Secondname Firstname".

Comment: Just to be clear, this is the default in the authoryear style - it's completely style dependant.

Comment: I agree. It is a style, not a bug. However, surnames first for all authors is widespread (at least in biological sciences, e.g., is a rule of the NLM style.) so it is not surprising that {first-last/last-first} default dance could baffle people.

Answer (score 6):

Just add `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}` to your preamble.

Consider the output of the following [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228):

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Abramowitz,
author = "Abramowitz, M. and Stegun, I.",
title  = "Handbook of Mathematical Functions",
publisher = {Dover Publications},
year = "1965" }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]